# Google Firestore - Fetch latest updates and display on the browser using JS

Tags: javascript, web, google-cloud-firestore

I have a spark job that pulls streaming data (Dstreams) with an interval of 100 seconds and sliding interval of 300 seconds and updates the firestore db at the end of every interval .I am able to manage all the above besides displaying the data from the firestore on the web since i do not have any frontend experience .

Below is what i have managed to write .

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firestore);

const firestoreDB = admin.firestore()

exports.triggerDoc = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 console.log("function triggered")
 triggerDocumentUpdated()
});

function triggerDocumentUpdated() {
  exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
      .document('men-clothing/accessories')
      .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const newValue = change.after.data();
        const previousValue = change.before.data();

        const name = newValue.name;
        console.log(name)
      });
}
```

I just want to display the updated values on the web and everytime i access the function URL after deploying my function , it shows up a "Error: could not handle the request" .

Not sure where i am going wrong . Any advice will be highly appreciated .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: seriously..?? ...nobody in the whole community seems to have any idea about this..